# Do some baby's eyes produce water more than others?

Tags: newborn, crying, eyes

Our 12 week old daughter has watery eyes occasionally, even when she isn't crying. She produced tears from a few days old, which has been remarked on by others as unusual.

It doesn't seem to cause her any discomfort, and I guess it could be because she barely ever blinks, and is constantly staring with wide eyed wonder at this new world of hers. (Or it could be hayfever.)

We are going to the doctors just to get her checked out, but I suspect they will say it is nothing, unless I can provide some suggestions.

Do some babies have watery eyes in absence of an allergy or medical issue? What else could cause this?

Comment: I would ask your pediatrician about this.  As with many things at this age, odds are it's nothing, but your pediatrician should be familiar with your child and her symptoms.

Comment: Please go to a doctor/ped. You can get suggestions from forums, but you need to consult a doctor on this.

Comment: Again, this wasn't a request for medical advice - I was expecting answers like "some kids don't blink enough", or "it's because they are so wide eyed and trying to take everything in". But anyway, we've got an appointment with the Doctor, so the responses have helped me.

Comment: Even in your new form the question was very open ended and essentially a poll of other people's experience. That format doesn't tend to work well on these Q/A sites so I edited it to ask a more concrete/closed-form question that has a right answer. If I didn't quite capture your specific question, please edit again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the Mayo Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/symptoms/watery-eyes/basics/causes/sym-20050821),

> **Infants**
>
> In infants, the most common cause of persistent watery eyes is a blocked or incompletely opened tear duct. The tears may dry out and appear crusty, but not necessarily due to infection. Within a few months, most blocked tear ducts in infants resolve on their own.

Though as the comments have said, talk with your pediatrician about this as it could be an infection or other medical issue.